# Angular2 QuickStart : Http Nor found

Tags: angular, angular-http

I have been installing  the Angular2 quickstart (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart).

I have the following modules :

- app/

  - components/

    - Module 1/

      - module1.component.ts
      - module1.html
  - services/

    - request.service.ts
  - app.component.ts
  - app.module.ts
  - main.ts

The Request service is importing Http from @angular/Http.
The Request service is imported in app.module.ts.

When launching the app with command **npm start** I have a 404 error on **"/@angular/Http"** . I've checked the @angular/ directory and http module is loaded, (the dependency line is also in the package.json file I know this was an issue in a previous version of the quickstart)

[image]

The **request service** does not throw errors :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/Http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class RequestService {

 constructor(private http:Http) {}

 sendRequest(type:string , url:string, parameters:Object) : void {
  // some code here
 }

}
```

And the **app.module.ts** seems pretty simple

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

/* SERVICES */

import { RequestService } from './services/request.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ RequestService ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I don't really know why the Http module won't load since the sources are available in my @angular directory. Am I missing something ? Should I declare something somewhere else ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `HttpModule` in your `app.module`

```ts
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ], // add HttpModule
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ RequestService ]
})
```

Comment: did this answer help you? :)